# little thud, thud, tap, tap

Tags: expressions, idioms

What do you mean or express by this expression

> Sometimes you'll get a little thud, thud, tap, tap

I tried to translate "..thud, thud, tap, tap" and failed!

Comment: Hello, user124335, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I've never had occasion to say "Sometimes you'll get a little thud, thud, tap, tap," so I'm not at all sure what someone who does say it has in mind. Can you provide more information about the circumstances or context where the saying came up? Thanks!

Comment: Any relation to "nudge nudge, wink wink"?

Comment: thanks dear, he is a fisher, speaking about fish :
" They're a bit of a, a bit of a, hard-core predator. So

they'll just sit there and they'll just come along and grab 

hold a your bait pretty hard. Sometimes you'll get a 

little thud, thud, tap, tap ... "
I hope to give me a detailed answer if you never mind!

Comment: Look up "thud" and "tap".  Those are sounds.  Eg, the speaker may be describing the sound his car makes in the morning.

Answer (score 2):

These words and many others that occur in each written language are called (in English) *onomatopoea (adj. onomatopoeic)*. This means they try to imitate, phonetically, a natural or man-made sound.

http://i.word.com/idictionary/onomatopoeia

Of course, these vary widely across languages, as various languages have different sets of *phonemes*, and to some degree, different sounds to imitate.

In USA dogs "bark", "yip " or "growl", yet the most common way to write a couple of barks is *arf arf*.

Rroosters "crow" in English, making a sound that we write as "cock-a-doodle-doo", but which in Spanish is rendered as "chi-chi-ri-chi".  (Personally, I think neither of these are dven close; I hear a rooster's crow as "rr-er-ERR-er".)

But the point is, you can't always just translate. You need to know what choices are available for representing sounds in the target language, and choose accordingly.

Alternatively, you may need to go to the definition of (for instance) "thud"

- A loud, dull sound, made especially when a heavy object hits something.

(http://i.word.com/idictionary/thud)

and then find corresponding words (not a single word) in the target language to match this description.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to build up an image in your mind. Consider a heavy door. You want the person on the other side to open it. You have basically two choices. If you clench your fist and hit the door with the bottom of your fist, the sound you make is a thud. If you hit it (not too hard) with your knuckle, the sound you make is a tap. (The action you take is to "rap" on the door, but the sound is a tap.)

The difference in sounds is what is being described in your example. "You'll get", in this case, means "You will produce".